# Accessing object through variable in JAVA for Window based application

Tags: java, excel, swing, user-interface, apache-poi

So, I am developing a GUI based application that reads data from Excel using Apache POI and displays it using `JAVA AWT/SWING` based Window Application. So, to start with I have integrated Apache `POI` in `GUI` based `JAVA` project.

So, now I am trying to access a particular cell data from excel and print it in the GUI App.
I have sorted out how to get particular cell data from excel to Java and how to use `Jlabel`. To proceed it with I need to send the cell data to `JLabel`.

I have done the following to get Cell data: Clearly, we have `cell` object from `Cell` class. How do I send this `cell` data to `JLabel`?

I have the following code for `JLabel`.

```
try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mohin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\a.xlsx")) {  
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);  
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
            Row row = sheet.getRow(2);  
            Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
            if (cell != null)  
                System.out.println("Data: "+cell);  
            else  
                System.out.println("Cell is empty");  
    }catch(Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }
```

Clearly we have `cell` object from `Cell` class. How do I send this `cell` data to `JLable`?

I have the following code for `JLable`.

Here after we press the button the content of the `Lable` changes.

```
lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hey there. Your GPA is");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(100, 46, 298, 55);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);


JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Show me!");
        btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
                lblNewLabel.setText(cell);
            }
        });
```

`lblNewLabel.setText(cell);`

But it's showing error. I even declared a new string and passed it using `cell` object. But it didn't work either.

I am looking for a way to pass the output from Cell to `JLabel`.

Both are in the main function only.

Below is the entire code.

```
package com;

import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;  
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;  
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mohin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\a.xlsx")) {  
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);  
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
            Row row = sheet.getRow(2);  
            Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
            if (cell != null)  
                System.out.println("Data: "+cell);  
            else  
                System.out.println("Cell is empty");  
    }catch(Exception e) {  
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 605, 418);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Show me!");
        btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
                lblNewLabel.setText(cell);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(147, 133, 130, 31);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hey there. Your GPA is");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(100, 46, 298, 55);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(63, 214, 96, 19);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(342, 214, 96, 19);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Answer-");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(139, 323, 122, 48);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(301, 329, 174, 42);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Multiply");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int a,b,ans;
                try {
                    a=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    b=Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                    ans=a*b;
                    textField_2.setText(Integer.toString(ans));

                }catch(Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter valid number");
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(90, 264, 85, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Divide");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int a,b,ans;
                try {
                    a=Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    b=Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                    ans=a/b;
                    textField_2.setText(Integer.toString(ans));

                }catch(Exception e2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter valid number");
                }
            }
        });

        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(330, 264, 85, 21);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);
    }
}
```

Don't mind all other GUI code. They are just some bunch of buttons, text fields.

Comment: *"Don't mind all other GUI code."* Don't include the other GUI code, if it's not relevant. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). General tip: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `cell`, but it is defined in another scope.
You could create method, which returns the cell-string.

```
public String getCell() {
        try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mohin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\a.xlsx")) {  
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);  
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
        Row row = sheet.getRow(2);  
        Cell cell = row.getCell(2);
        if (cell != null)  
            return cell.toString(); 
}catch(Exception e) {  
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

return null;
    }
and then access it like so:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Show me!");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
            lblNewLabel.setText(getCell());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah but the first method to get cell content should return some value right? and then we can call it in JButton.I mean the method should return value in cell. So shall i try if(cell!=null){return cell;} ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that. put a return null in the catch block and do if (cell != null) return cell;

Comment: I'll try it. :-)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't print the exception, instead of "System.out.println(e); ", use "e.printStackTrace();"

Comment: I tried it's not working. Somewhere I couldn't map all of them correctly.

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: Please update your full code and show me again what you have. I don't understand, what is not working?

Comment: Can I get your mail ID?

Comment: julien.rrheinbach@gmail.com

Comment: Yeah here's the final answer. I have updated it directly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `Cell cell` in the scope of the `initialize` method or the `Cell cell` would must be a class member as `JLabel lblNewLabel` also is.

Another solution would be having a public method to get the cell content from the workbook which then can be called from within the `initialize` method.

Then, the `setText` method of a `JLabel` needs a `String` as the parameter. So you need converting the content of the `cell` to `String`.

So simplest solution would be

```
...
String cellContent = cell.toString();
...
```

But that is not the preferred way to do it. Instead do using `DataFormatter` of `apache poi` to get the cell content out of the `Cell` as a `String`. `DataFormatter` will get that `String` the same as `Excel` shows the cell content.

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
String cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
...
```

If there can be formula cells and you need the formula results instead of the formulas, then you will need `FormulaEvaluator` additionally.

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
String cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
...
```

So to extend your code you could have following method:

```
...
public String getCellContent() {
 String cellContent = "";
 try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\mohin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\a.xlsx"); 
      Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp)) {  
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);  
  Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
  Cell cell = null;
  if (row != null) cell = row.getCell(2);
  cellContent = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return cellContent;
}
...
```

And then in your `initialize` method:

```
...
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
                lblNewLabel.setText(getCellContent());
            }
...
```

But of course this will always get the same cell content from the sheet. So for practical usage the `getCellContent` would must have parameters to tell what concrete cell shall be read. And then the method should not open the workbook every single time a cell content shall got. So `Workbook wb`, `DataFormatter formatter` and `FormulaEvaluator evaluator` should be class members and created only once while `initialize`.

Comment: Hey there! Your solution is working but I couldn't access the cellContent in JButton method . Can you please guide me through it?

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter. YOur solution worked out very well. :-)